# Devise few users cannot reset passwords and get locked out

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

'devise', '3.4.1'
'rails', '4.1.8'
ruby '2.1.2'

Reset password works with most users but not with others, I have noticed with these users devise fails to save reset_password_sent_at time.

Point me in the right direction if you can...I will add code if needed, just ask.

```
#devise.rb
config.reset_password_within = 36.hours

#routes
devise_for :users,
controllers: {
registrations: 'registrations',
confirmations: "confirmations", :omniauth_callbacks =>       "users/omniauth_callbacks"
}

resources :users

#user.rb
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :validatable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable,  :confirmable, :omniauthable,
     :omniauth_providers => [:facebook, :twitter, :google, :linkedin]
```